# choose wrong option during install and lost partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows, hard-drive, boot-partition

i tried ubuntu 13.04 beta in my pc with live dvd.

when i wanted to install ubuntu i choose to delete my windows wrongly!.

i see the page that we must to select time location and here i realized my mistake so quickly cancel the installatio. but i lost my partitions.
is there any hope that i recover my files and partitions?.i have really important information on it.
please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't write any more on your disc, including don't boot on your installed Ubuntu.
2. Use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to fix your partition table. If still not good, use TestDisk to recover your lost files.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in this scenario, your files have not been deleted but the map to those files has. Sometimes you can restore these easily. Download the Ultimate Boot CD and try some tools on there http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

Comment: Generally speaking, more information of how the could use that tool is more advisable.